# conditional disabling of navigator/scrollbar

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to implement dynamic loading data for my chart. I've seen exapmle on [site](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading), but in my case I cannot know how long can be my chart and what is my latest date. I load new part of data when scrollbar approaches to the begining of axis then add the new part to existing one. The problem is when data is loading I want to disable navigator and scrollbar (do not hide it just prevent dargging) and after loading to enable it again.
I tried to use e.preventDefault in setExtremes handler but anyway scroll moves.
Is it possible to implement it? Any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: SO you have chart with data, add during adding new data, navigator/scrollbar should be disabled, am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not supported, but you can request your suggestion on the http://highcharts.uservoice.com/ website